# Nullspace of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I've gotten a little help on the following problem, but I'm still having trouble with it:

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a linear transformation. We define the nullspace of $T$ to be 
$$Null(T)=\{\mathbf{x} ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n} ∶ T(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{0}\}.$$

Find a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^{5}→\mathbb{R}^{2}$ such that

$$Null(T)=\{(x_1,…,x_5) ∈ \mathbb{R}^{5} ∶x_4=x_5=0\}$$

This is the help I got from a friend:

" Define $T(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)=(x4,x5)$

$T$ is a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^{5}→\mathbb{R}^{2}$

$Null(T)=\{x ∈ \mathbb{R}^{5} ∶x_4=x_5=0\}$ "

It seems like this doesn't quite answer the question. 
Please help me out!

Comment: Your friend's solution is correct. If you do take his proposition into account, any vector of the form $(x_1,x_2,x_3,0,0)$ is in the null space, and notice how any vector of that form has $x_4 = x_5 = 0$, which is what the question wanted.

Comment: What makes you think that this definition of $T$ doesn't answer the question?  What do you think is missing or wrong?

Comment: Thank you! It just seemed to me simply a reformulation of the original problem, not adding any new information. I'm very green at this, and I didn't think it could be this simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work: define your transformation on the standard bases {$e_i$} , with $e_i$ a "5-vector" with i-th component 1 , and 0 otherwise. Then, define $T(e_i)=0$ for $ i= 1,2,3$ . Then define $T(e_4)=(1,0)$ and $T(e_5)=(0,1)$. Then {$T(e_4),T(e_5)$} is a basis for $\mathbb R^2$, so it must have trivial kernel.

We can verify this works using rank-nullity. We have that $Dim (Im(T))=Dim(\mathbb R^2)=2$, since the image (span) of T{$e_4,e_5$} is the whole of $\mathbb R^2$, and we know that the dimension of the nullspace is $3$, since the three vectors $e_i; i=1,2,3$ are linearly-independent, so they span a nullset of dimension 3. Since the map is from $\mathbb R^5$, we have Rank(T)+Nullity(T)=5

Comment: Thanks! I'll need some time to digest this one.

Comment: No problem, Hal, take your time and ask a followup if you need to.